# How to fix 'undefined method' enum in rspec test with FactoryBot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, factory-bot

I'm trying to test an model I had created for my application, it has association with two other models, also using Factory Bot to build the test, however it does not recognize it, the error return is: `Failure/Error: status :pending //// NoMethodError: undefined method 'status' in 'pending' factory.`

I'm running the application with Ruby 2.6.1, Rails 5.2.3, FactoryBot 5.0.2, Rspec 3.8. I've tried the different ways to define an enum. I don't know what to do more.

Model:

```
class CollegeWhitelist < ApplicationRecord
    enum status: {pending: 0, approved: 1, rejected: 2}

    has_many :users
    has_many :colleges
end
```

Factory:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :college_whitelist do
    association :user
    association :college

    trait :pending do
      status :pending
    end

    trait :approved do
      status :approved
    end

    trait :rejected do
      status :rejected
    end
  end
end
```

Rspec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe CollegeWhitelist, type: :model do
  describe "#consistency " do
    it 'cannot insert the same user for the same college in permissions' do
      @permission = build(:college_whitelist)
      p @permission
    end
  end
end
```

I was expecting it to pass the test just printing the object at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of naming clashing.

You must wrap the value of the `status` column within curly brackets otherwise it'll call itself:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :college_whitelist do
    ...

    trait :pending do
      status { :pending }
    end

    trait :approved do
      status { :approved }
    end

    trait :rejected do
      status { :rejected }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what was missing! I had found a issue in FactoryBot repository talking about this, they said a change would be made to throw a more specific error, but it still returns the generic error. Link to the issue comment that tells about this: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/issues/1264#issuecomment-462759569
Thanks Sebastian !